# Publishing library to Bintray from Android Studio hangs

Tags: android, android-library

I'm following [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) tutorial to publish an Android library to Bintray. However, the `gradlew bintrayUpload` task hangs forever without an error message. How can I debug this process?

Comment: unless you need bintray, consider using jitpack.io

Comment: Thanks, Marcin. I'm looking to publish the library to jcenter, is that supported by jitpack as well?

Comment: no. jitpack is jitpack, bintray is bintray, yet publishing to jitpack is simplier. So if this is library you release publicly, I recommend trying jitpack. Docs: https://jitpack.io/docs/#publishing-on-jitpack

Comment: Bintray allows publishing to jcenter with a single click. I don't want to force developers to add an additional repository to their gradle file, so I'll have to stick with Bintray.

Comment: as you wish. but if they are already using 3rd party libs they most likely already got jitpack in gradle anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the script again with the `--stacktrace` option, the console showed the error and I was able to fix it.